# What do minWidth(forHeight) ,minHeight(forWidth), ...mean?

Tags: java, javafx

I was reading the [javafx region online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#maxHeightProperty) and came across minWidth(forHeight),minHeight(forWidth),getPrefWidth(forHeight),getPrefHeight(forWidth), getMaxWidth(forHeight), getMaxHeight(forWidth) etc. Basically it is height for width or width for height. I have no idea what does it mean. For example what does minWidth(forHeight) means? Why there is a parenthesis with forHeight in it?

Any help or explanation will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a regular method parameter to me.

Comment: Look at the text of your own question. To me, the first block of text is wrapped over 5 lines. Then there is a single line following it. Imaging the invisible box surrounding that text. If you change the width of that box, the lines will wrap differently, so the height might change. If you change the height of that box, the lines can wrap differently to fill the height, so the width might change. So, if you know the width, what is the height of the box: Call method `minHeight(double forWidth)`. If you want a certain height, what should the width of the box be: `minWidth(double forHeight)`.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for your response. I am kind of getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [`Region::minWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#minWidth-double-) javdoc:

> ```
> public final double minWidth(double height)
> ```
>
> Called during layout to determine the minimum width for this node.
>   Returns the value from `computeMinWidth(forHeight)` unless the
>   application overrode the minimum width by setting the minWidth
>   property.

Imagine you have a control which you wish to display by default in an area no smaller than a 16:9 display ratio, then an implementation of `computeMinWidth` might be:

```
protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
    return height * 16 / 9;
}
```

You never need to supply an implementation of `minWidth(height)` as the default implementation already suffices and will invoke your custom `computeMinWidth(height)` function.

*Background Info*

Unless you are writing your own layout handling code (usually by extending [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html) and overriding [`layoutChildren()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layoutChildren--)), it is unlikely you will every use the `Region::minWidth` method.  As mentioned in the Region javadoc it is more common to override [`computePrefWidth(height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#computePrefWidth-double-) when you are writing your own layout code, and in the `layoutChildren()` method call [`prefWidth()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#prefWidth-double-) method as needed.  Note that writing your own layout handling code isn't very common unless you are writing your own controls.  Usually, using the existing [layout panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/) with appropriate constraints set on them suffices and it is not necessary to code your own layout regions.  Coding your own layout regions can get complex if you take into account things like insets and snapping to pixels, so often it is not worth the trouble as the built-in layout panes and control implementations handle these complexities for your automatically.